# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having serious problem while adding .config in .ebextensions directory to install  imagemagick package in Amazon Linux managed under Elastic Beanstalk. I used

```
packages:
        yum:
            ImageMagick: []
```

When I tried to deploy the war from ELB console, process completed with error

> [Instance: i-531ab77a Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null]
>   Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred
>   during build: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys' .

Comment: Are you using spaces or tabs in .config? Only spaces can be used. Also, the documentation mentions that the config file should have a name, not just extension, although it might not be the issue in your case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have a space between "ImageMagick:" and "[]".

I was able to reproduce this error when I used "ImageMagick:[]" instead:

> [Instance: i-7079d32d Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys' .

Comment: Wow, saved the day. Very hard to track down.

Comment: Could also be the case with other sections in `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` so look carefully at _all_ the sections.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error for

```
sources:
      /home/ec2-user  http://azxc.net/certs.zip
```

Forgot to add ":" , This fixed error:

```
sources:
      /home/ec2-user:  http://azxc.net/certs.zip
```