# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys' - convert object to dictionary python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**The problem**

I am trying to convert an object into a dict for sqlite database creation. I am using an app called "tinytag" to pull the metadata from my mp4 on my computer.

When I run the function, I get a list of data that looks like key pairs but they are an object. I have tried to convert the variable into a dict using some code I found online but its pulling an error that I am not sure of.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from tinytag import TinyTag
import sqlite3
import json


tag = ''
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name)) 
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
            tag_str = str(tag)
            tag_json = json.loads(json.dumps(tag_str, default=lambda o: o.__dict__))

            
conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

for tablist in tag_json.keys():
    fieldset = []
    for col, definition in tag_json[tablist].items():
        fieldset.append("'{0}' {1}".format(col, definition))

    if len(fieldset) > 0:
        query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ({1})".format(tablist, ", ".join(fieldset))

        c.execute(query)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Here is what the `tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)` looks like if I print it:

```
{"album": "Final Fantasy VII", "albumartist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "artist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Role-playing Game", "composer": "Nobuo Uematsu", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 350.08306666666664, "filesize": 575693062, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Full-Scale Attack", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1997"}
{"album": "Final Fantasy VII", "albumartist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "artist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Role-playing Game", "composer": "Nobuo Uematsu", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 111.07763333333334, "filesize": 179760044, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Gold Saucer", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1997"}
{"album": "Final Fantasy VII", "albumartist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "artist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Role-playing Game", "composer": "Nobuo Uematsu", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 195.06153333333333, "filesize": 318267268, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Great Warrior", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1997"}
{"album": "Final Fantasy VII", "albumartist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "artist": "Nobuo Uematsu", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Role-playing Game", "composer": "Nobuo Uematsu", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 222.08853333333334, "filesize": 363059333, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Hollding My Thoughts in My heart", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1997"}
# over 6000 more songs left ...
```

Here is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//VGMSTATION/testing scripts/search and print2.py", line 35, in <module>
    for tablist in tag_json.keys():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

What I tried looking up but didn't help me or I didn't understand: [AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222161/attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-key)
['unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501137/unicode-object-has-no-attribute-keys)

Comment: It sounds like you might be dealing with tuples. Can you show some sample output from the app?

Comment: Did you  try `print(tag_json)` to see what is it ? You may leanr to debug by yourself a bit ;)

Comment: @norie - I updated the question to show what the output looks like if I print `tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)`

Comment: @azro - I tried printing `print(tag_json)` and it gave me one of the lines of my output of which I am trying to turn into a dict `{"album": "Spawn Armageddon", "albumartist": "Rik Schaffer", "artist": "Rik Schaffer", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Action-adventure", "composer": "Rik Schaffer", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 49.11573333333333, "filesize": 75479673, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": null, "track": "9", "track_total": "0", "year": "2003"}`

Comment: What happens if you use tag instead of tag_json to create the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff you're doing with your `TinyTag.get` output:

```
tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
tag_str = str(tag)
tag_json = json.loads(json.dumps(tag_str, default=lambda o: o.__dict__))
```

makes no sense. You're calling `str`, producing a string, then JSON dumping the *string*, then loading the JSON, giving you your string back. The dump/load step is entirely pointless, and the initial `str` is counterproductive.

(I suspect part of what lead you to this point is the terrible `__str__`/`__repr__` implementation used by this library, which makes its objects look like they're already dicts or some sort of JSON. They're not.)

To convert a TinyTag object to a dict, call its `as_dict` method:

```
tag_dict = TinyTag.get(musiclist).as_dict()
```

(I had to read the source code to find that - there's very little documentation for this module. If you want to stick to the documented interface, you'll have to pack all the documented attributes into a dict manually, but at that point, you might as well just use the object directly without dict conversion.)

Answer (score 0):

See the decoding of a json file and accessing keys and values. I created an example

```
import json

with open("example.json") as tag_json:  
    # json decoding
    data = json.load(tag_json)
    
    keys = data.keys()
    values = data.values()

print(keys, values)

"""prints dict_keys(['Emp_Info']) dict_values([[{'name': 'a', 'id': '123'}, {'name': 'b', 'id': '345'}]])"""

#access Keys
tag_data = data['Emp_Info'] #

for x in tag_data:
    print(x.keys(), x.values())

"""
dict_keys(['name', 'id']) dict_values(['a', '123'])
dict_keys(['name', 'id']) dict_values(['b', '345'])
"""
```